# Basic Question: how does feed-forward neural network solve regression?

Tags: neural-networks

This is a fairly basic question but I can't seem to find an answer on the net (perhaps I'm searching the wrong things).

Regression is trying to predict continuous outputs. Since a neural network uses a clamping function (typically giving a value between 0 and 1) before the output.. if the output can only be between 0 and 1, how can a neural network learn a regression function?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual solution is to provide an output layer which uses a linear neuron rather than the traditional sigmoid or tanh. This achieves the necessary infinite range from a finite range. A linear neuron simply outputs a linear combination of its inputs, usually with an added bias parameter for a constant term. The weights in the linear function and the bias are learnt by the network during training.

Comment: The linear output unit can only output the weighted sum of the layer before it. Say all weights were 1 and the outputs to the layer before this linear unit were $z_i$. In this case, the maximum value of $z_i$ is one, therefore the output unit has an upper bound of $n$ where $n$ is the number of units in the second to last layer. I don't see the network could output numbers greater than $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The input is usually normalized to a value between 0 to 1. After feeding it into the neural network the output will also be between 0 to 1. After which it is denormalized. The neural net works by finding the underlying relationship between the input and output mathetically. Think of it as a linear equation. However it is an approximate solution.